# Eloquent - Find - Static call

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Normally if you want to find a row by an id (primary key) you just do something like this:

```
$user = User::find(1);
```

Same for the `where`:

```
$result = User::where('votes', '>', 100);
```

Unfortunately i can't use this static call since i have a constructer in the model:

```
class PurchasesModel extends Eloquent
{
    public function __construct($connection) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->connection = $connection;
        $this->table = 'purchases';
    }
}
```

I searched the whole docs about that, but there are only static calls.

How can i do this?

```
$purchases = new PurchasesModel($this->connection);
$purchases->where('status', 'active');
$purchases->get();
```

Seems not to be work.

Thanks

Comment: Could you have your PurchaseModel like that and then make another model that extends PurchaseModel to do static calls from?

Comment: How should that work? I still need to parse the $connection to it?

Comment: Realized that didn't really make sense as soon as I posted, sorry been a long day. Let me see if I can't put something together.

Comment: No problem buddy :D I know that feeling. I appreciate that you tried to help me. I don't know if there is an easy solution we just don't know.. Otherwise this stuff is really weird :/

Comment: I am pretty sure you can define multiple databases then connect to them on the fly, which I believe is similar to what your trying to do. I could be reading what your trying to do wrong though.

Comment: Even if this would be possible (what isn't as i know) it would not make sense since this are 2 completly different databases, so i need to do it like i do :/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33304/discussion-between-matthew-camp-and-michael)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the same variable repeatedly for querying you need to re-assign the variable so that changes take effect. So you'd end up with something like this.

```php
$purchases = new PurchasesModel($this->connection);
$purchases = $purchases->where('status', 'active');
$purchases = $purchases->get();
```

Honestly, I'd just do it like this.

```php
$purchases = new PurchasesModel($this->connection);
$purchases = $purchases->where('status', 'active')->get();
```

But luckily for you you can already begin an Eloquent query with a different connection.

```php
$purchases = PurchasesModel::on($this->connection)->where('status', 'active')->get();
```

---

After a chat with @Michael we deemed it to be a problem with overloading the Eloquent constructor. Because Eloquent instantiates itself in a few places (static calls to find, with, etc) it makes it hard for Eloquent because it assumes that the first parameter is going to be an optional array of attributes for the model.

Comment: Unfortunately the static call won't work like this. I can't do a static call since i have the constructer inside, otherwise i get an exception. So for example how can i use `find(1)`?

Comment: You can still use find, it'll all through to the Eloquent query builder. `PurchasesModel::on($this->connection)->find(1);`

Comment: As i wrote i can't do a static call since i have a constructer inside the method(model). :/

Comment: Let's [take this into a chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33340/eloquent-find-static-call).